# RuntimeException catching in request listener -> Twig error template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a kernel listener bound to a `kernel.request` event, which can throw a PHP `\RuntimeException` in certain cases. Whereas in dev env Symfony catches the exception and shows me the Twig error page for 'Fatal error', in prod env I just keep getting an empty page. This is a `200 OK` HTTP response, but it has no content.

What I'd like to achieve is showing a customised error page - i.e. 'Wrong application configuration', which will actually be of any use for the end user trying to reach the page. This is a fatal error, but - well - it can eventually happen.

I tried catching it in my exception listener which gets executed on `kernel.exception` event, but it seems not to be catching a 'fatal error' exception.

**Here's what I've tried so far**

- kernel.exception event listener
- throwing a 'normal' `\Exception` (thought that maybe that's the case). Seems that an exception thrown from within a listener does not fire the kernel.exception event as well...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I seem to have found the answer.

The problem was the order of services' definitions. When you tag a service to bind one of its methods to a `kernel.exception` event, it needs to be - of course - declared in your services' config before you throw an exception in any other listener. Or any other place, as a matter of fact.